# c# repeater: I get one value from an indexed control in code behind but can't get others... why?

Tags: c#, asprepeater

I'm using a repeater with a DbDataReader which displays all data correctly in the .aspx.  I want to access specific columns and rows int the repeater in the code behind.  I can get only one but not the others and I can't figure out why.  Here is a shortened sql statement that I'm using:

```
sql = "select distinct question_explain_int as competency_int,dbo.CodeDescription('competency', question_explain_int, 0) as competency";
sql += " from test_content tc left join test_question tq on tc.question_int = tq.question_int where dbo.CodeDescription('competency', question_explain_int, 0) <> ''";
   DbDataReader rs = CADEdata.ReadData(cnxn, sql);
   competencyRepeater.DataSource = rs;
   competencyRepeater.DataBind();
```

So, I can get competency with:

```
((Label)competencyRepeater.Items[0].FindControl("competency")).Text    
((Label)competencyRepeater.Items[1].FindControl("competency")).Text
```

But the following returns null!

```
((Label)competencyRepeater.Items[0].FindControl("competency_int")).Text    
((Label)competencyRepeater.Items[1].FindControl("competency_int")).Text
```

Actually, I have a lot more columns and they all return null except the one.  What's going on and how can I get the other values?

EDIT #1:
I thought I found the solution, competency_int is a hidden field in the .aspx so I switched to the following format but it is still null:

```
<input type="hidden" name="competency_int" id="competency_int<%#Container.ItemIndex%>" value="<%# Eval("competency_int") %>" />
```

...

```
   ((HiddenField)competencyRepeater.Items[1].FindControl("competency_int")).Value
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the left join.  I would start with a simpler query (no left join) and see if you get more than one column.  The make query more complex until you find what is causing the issue.

Comment: Like I said, data is fine in aspx... also displays data and columns fine in SSMS.  If it can't deal with a complex sql statement there would be no reason to use a repeater.

Comment: You didn't say that you were using SQL Server and the query was tested.  is the connection string in aspx the same as in c#?  When you display in aspx are the column names the same as in c#?  Is competencyRepeater a 3rd party dll?  The error may be in the dll.

Comment: You're correct MSSQL and good query. Connection strings are the same.  Repeater is standard in VS 2019.